# How to separate a 1D list into a 2D list with 1D lists of decreasing length, down to 1

Tags: python, arrays

If I had the 1D list:

`[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]`

How would I separate the 1D list so that it would make a 2D list that has 1D elements of decreasing length, down to 1?

For example, the above list would become:

`[[1,2,3,4][5,6,7][8,9][10]]`

I am aware this only works with lists of certain lengths, but in this case I only need it to work for those ideal lengths.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Can you think of a mathematical rule that tells you, how many elements should be in the first list? Can you write code that gives you the first list, if you know how many elements it should have? Can you write code that tells you the number of elements for each other list? Can you write code that makes those lists, given their lengths? (Hint: think about where they should start, based on where the previous lists ended.) If you put these things together, does it solve the problem?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

#### With a generator

Let's make a generator which will return the elements of a list as if they were in a flattened triangular matrix:

```
def tril(arr):
    '''Iterate over the list as a lower triangular matrix,
    e.g. if arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10] then return one by one:
    [1]
    [2, 3]
    [4, 5, 6]
    [7, 8, 9, 10]
    '''
    N = len(arr)
    left, width = 0, 1
    while left < N:
        yield arr[left:(right:=left+width)]
        left = right
        width += 1
```

With `[i for i in tril([*range(1,11)])` we get a list:

```
[[1], [2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9, 10]]
```

So to get the required answer we have to apply reversing three times - to a given list `arr = [*range(1,11)]`, to each item from `tril(reversed(arr))`, and to the whole output list:

```
arr = [*range(1, 11)]
answer = [i[::-1] for i in tril(arr[::-1])][::-1]
```

#### Knowing the lenght of the first item

We can calculate the length of the first item from the equation:

```
n*(n+1) == 2*len(arr)
```

where `arr` is a given list if items, and `n` is the lenght of the first item of the required answer, e.g if `arr = [*range(1, 11)]` then `n == 4`. In other words, `len(arr)` is equal to the sum of first `n` natural numbers.

So we can obtain the answer this way:

```
arr = [*range(1, 11)]
n = round(((8*len(arr) + 1)**0.5 - 1)/2)

# Usually we know the value of n
# so only the next 2 lines is needed in common case
item = iter(arr)
answer = [[next(item) for _ in range(i)] for i in range(n, 0, -1)]
```